# How to insert Date object with the latest mongojack?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, mongojack

so in my object, I have  `private Date date;` when I insert I got this exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonGenerator of type org.mongojack.internal.object.document.DocumentObjectGenerator not supported: org.mongojack.internal.DateSerializer is designed for use only with org.mongojack.internal.object.BsonObjectGenerator or org.mongojack.internal.stream.DBEncoderBsonGenerator or com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer (through reference chain: com.test.DocumentWrapper["date"])
```

I am trying to set up the mongo TTL by using that date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same issue recently: to store date as Date object into MongoDB via MongoJack.
First of all, I used MongoJack 2.10.0 version.
And it requires to create own Serializer and Deserializer.

```
public class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeObject(new Date(value.getMillis()));
    }
}

public class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DateTime> {

private static final DateDeserializer DATE_DESERIALIZER = new DateDeserializer();

    @Override
    public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Date date = DATE_DESERIALIZER.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        return date == null ? null : new DateTime(date);
    }
}

.....
@JsonSerialize(using = Serializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)
private DateTime testDate;

public DateTime getTestDate() {
    return testDate;
}

public void setTestDate(DateTime testDate) {
    this.testDate = testDate;
}
......
```

In my case, I converted Date into joda DateTime to keep consistency with my code but it's possible to change to another type (LocalDateTime, OffsetDateTime, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, please use the 2.10.0 version which has fixed this bug.